# Parallelized Matrix Multiplication

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication, java-threads

I am trying to parallelize the multiplication of two matrix `A`,`B`.

Unfortunately the serial implementation is still faster than the parallel one or the speedup is too low. (with matrix dimension = 512 the speedup is like `1.3`). Probably something is fundamentally wrong. Can someone out there give me a tip?

```java
double[][] matParallel2(final double[][] matrixA,
                        final double[][] matrixB,
                        final boolean parallel) {
    int rows = matrixA.length;
    int columnsA = matrixA[0].length;
    int columnsB = matrixB[0].length;

    Runnable task;
    List<Thread> pool = new ArrayList<>();

    double[][] returnMatrix = new double[rows][columnsB];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        task = () -> {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnsB; j++) {
                //  returnMatrix[finalI][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < columnsA; k++) {
                    returnMatrix[finalI][j] +=
                            matrixA[finalI][k] * matrixB[k][j];
                }
            }
        };
        pool.add(new Thread(task));
    }
    if (parallel) {
        for (Thread trd : pool) {
            trd.start();
        }
    } else {
        for (Thread trd : pool) {
            trd.run();
        }
    }
    try {
        for (Thread trd : pool) {
            trd.join();
        }
    } catch (
            Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnMatrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *one [`parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#parallel--) stream* to reduce the computation time (perhaps twice or more). Don't use nested parallelism because this gives the opposite effect!

```java
/**
 * Parallel Matrix multiplication
 *
 * @param m rows of 'a' matrix
 * @param n columns of 'a' matrix
 *          and rows of 'b' matrix
 * @param p columns of 'b' matrix
 * @param a first matrix 'm×n'
 * @param b second matrix 'n×p'
 * @return result matrix 'm×p'
 */
static double[][] parallelMatrixMultiplication(
        int m, int n, int p, double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    return IntStream.range(0, m)
            .parallel() // comment this line to check the sequential stream
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, p)
                    .mapToDouble(j -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                            .mapToDouble(k -> a[i][k] * b[k][j])
                            .sum())
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(double[][]::new);
}
```

---

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // dimensions
    int m = 512;
    int n = 1024;
    int p = 512;

    // matrices
    double[][] a = randomMatrix(m, n);
    double[][] b = randomMatrix(n, p);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // multiplication
    double[][] c = parallelMatrixMultiplication(m, n, p, a, b);

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
    // with    .parallel() the time is - 1495
    // without .parallel() the time is - 5823
}
```

```java
static double[][] randomMatrix(int d1, int d2) {
    return IntStream.range(0, d1)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, d2)
                    .mapToDouble(j -> Math.random() * 10)
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(double[][]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong.

Creating a thread means a huge overhead, compared to a few multiplications. Currently, for 512*512 matrices, you create 512 threads. Your CPU surely has less than 512 cores, so only e.g. 8 or 16 of them will really run in parallel on different cores, but the ~500 others also consumed the creation overhead without increasing parallel execution.

Try to limit the number of threads to something closer to the number of CPU cores, either with your own logic, or by using a framework, e.g. the java.util.concurrent package.