# Parallelize the generation of combinations

Tags: java, parallel-processing, combinations

I have an n array and I each array  contains 600 elements. I need to generate all combinations in a following way:

```
tab1={0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...}
tab2={0.5, 0.1, 0.3, ...}
tab3={0.8, 0.6, 0.2, ...} // 600 elements
```

the combinations:

```
combination1={0.6, 0.5, 0.8}
combination2={0.6, 0.5, 0.6}
...
```

The generation of all possible compositions is time-consuming process. Actually I have 6 arrays, that's why I need parallel processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parallel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) *stream* to reduce the computation time by about half. For example, combinations of three `double[]` arrays of 300 elements:

```java
/**
 * @param arrays an arbitrary number of arrays.
 * @return the Cartesian product of the passed arrays.
 */
public static double[][] parallelCombinations(double[]... arrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrays)
            // represent each array element as a single element array
            .map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(d -> new double[]{d})
                    // Stream<double[][]>
                    .toArray(double[][]::new))
            // summation of pairs of inner arrays in parallel
            .reduce((arr1, arr2) -> Arrays.stream(arr1)
                    // comment this line to check the sequential stream
                    .parallel()
                    // combinations of inner arrays
                    .flatMap(inner1 -> Arrays.stream(arr2)
                            // merge two inner arrays into one
                            .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                                    .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream)
                                    .toArray()))
                    // array of combinations
                    .toArray(double[][]::new))
            // otherwise an empty 2d array
            .orElse(new double[][]{});
}
```

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // size of arrays
    int size = 300;
    // prepare arrays
    double[] arr1 = doubleArray(0, size);
    double[] arr2 = doubleArray(size, size);
    double[] arr3 = doubleArray(size * 2, size);

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // array of combinations
    double[][] combinations = parallelCombinations(arr1, arr2, arr3);

    // output
    System.out.println("Combinations: " + combinations.length);
    // Combinations: 27000000
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
    // with    .parallel() the time is - 10321
    // without .parallel() the time is - 23468
}
```

```java
public static double[] doubleArray(int from, int size) {
    // sequentially filled array of doubles
    return DoubleStream.iterate(from / 10.0, d -> d + 0.1).limit(size).toArray();
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Parallelized Matrix Multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000825/15675591)</sup>